# An error occured during vote count fetch - For a user with < 1K rep

Tags: bug, reputation, voting, vote-count

AFAIK only users with reputation > 1K can view vote split on a post, by clicking the current vote score. For users with reputation < 1K clicking on the vote score does nothing.

But I got an error message when clicking the vote score on meta.stackoverflow.com (where my reputation < 1K)

[image]

Not a major one. But looks like a bug.

PS : Mac Mountain Lion, Chrome Version 27.0.1453.93

Comment: You are using [this script](http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) IMO because users without privilege can't click on vote count. Also this error occurs to me during internet connection problem.

Comment: @hims056 I doubt whether I am using that script. I never seen that before, and no one else normally use my machine. Any idea to check whether I am unknowingly using it or not?

Comment: In Chrome there is an extension named *Tampermonkey*. See whether it is running or not. If it is running, check whether this script is running or not.

Comment: Try to browse directly to [this link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/182333/vote-counts?_=1369913372169). What do you get?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I am getting "Oops! This link appears to be broken."

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Another hidden feature. Thanks. :)

Comment: @hims when I take chrome->Window->Extension it says "*Boo... You have no extensions :-(*"

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, that you got that error, and the "broken link" error, just confirms that you are seeing vote totals via the userscript you have installed, and not via SE's built-in mechanism.

Comment: Everyone just a help, how would I check that any userscript is running ? I am damn sure I never installed one(since I am the only one who use this machine, I don't know what userscript is).

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be able to click the vote count. The bug is that you can click it with less than 1000 reputation.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I am having less than 1000 rep in [Android.SE]. But I am not able to click on votes there.

Comment: @hims056 I know, can't reproduce this either. Maybe specific to Mountain Lion which I don't have..

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I believe this question is off topic only if I am using any userscript, which I don't. Someone close it as too localized. Anyway, I am done with this.

Comment: @hims056 try the steps [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182333/152859). :)

Comment: How come this question is a duplicate of another question asked 18 days later?